# Show loading indicator in React Native when rendering screens

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm making an app with React Native, and I have a doubt. I have a navigator with various screens. When the screens are small / easy, the navigation is instant and it feels fast, but when the screen I need to navigate to is big / shows a lot of icons/images, etc., the screen freezes when I press the navigation button untils it renders the screen and then it navigates there.

Is there any way to show a loading indicator when this happens? Because my screens are taking 500 to 1000ms to render and it makes the UX bad by freezing.

Comment: In big screens, you get data from the server? Or it's a static Data

Comment: From the server, but I already got it hooked with redux and redux thunk, I display a loading indicator when it's fetching data from the server, but then I pass this data to the  "sub-screens" and it freezes because of the rendering

Comment: did you check how many times render method get called?

Comment: Just the one, thing is, I thought this was a common problem but I tried searching and  I'm not finding anything...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Expo, try to use the `<AppLoading />` component, this allows to load some files like images before.
Here's the link to the documentation 
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/app-loading/

Comment: If I do not use Expo?